# Dynamic Caching in NextJs app using Service Worker

Tags: javascript, next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, browser-cache

I'm trying to dynamically cache pages on the browser, but what is happening is, even if I don't cache a page, and call it in offline mode, the page is loaded.
The limitCache function also doesn't seems to work.

This service worker resides in sw.js file which is present in public folder.

Here is the service worker code

```js
const staticCache = 'site-static-v1'
const dynamicCache ='site-dy-v1'
const assets=[
    '/index.js',
    '/app.js',
    '/fallback.js',
    '/styles/globals.css',
];//storing request urls
this.addEventListener('install',(e) => {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCache).then(cache => {
        // cache.add() //single item
        console.log("Caching log Assests")
        cache.addAll(assets)// array of item
      })
    )
     //async task, return a promise
})
self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then( keys => {
            return Promise.all(keys
                .filter(key => key !== staticCache )
                .map(key => caches.delete(key)))
        })
    )
})

const limitCacheSize = (name, size) => {
    caches.open(name).then((cache) => {
      cache.keys().then((keys) => {
        if (keys.length > size) {
          cache.delete(keys[0]).then(limitCacheSize(name, size));
        }
      });
    });
  };


self.addEventListener('fetch',(e) => {
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then(cacheRes => {
            return cacheRes || fetch(e.request).then(fetctRes => {
                return caches.open(dynamicCache).then(cache => {
                    cache.put(e.request.url,fetctRes.clone())
                    .then( () =>{limitCacheSize(dynamicCache,6)});
                    return fetctRes;
                })
            });
        }).catch(() => caches.match('../fallback.js').then(fetchRes =>{return fetchRes}))
    );// console.log(e)
});
```

I tried running the code on different browsers, none of the browsers cached the pages properly